# htaccess : rewrite /?page=x to /page/x

Tags: .htaccess

My site URL is like this:

```
http://site.com/category/?page=1
```

I want be :

```
http://site.com/category/page/1
```

I use this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/$ /?page=$1
```

But not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/page/(.*) /category/?page=$1
```

because if you write `^page/(.*)/$` you say : my URL must begin with *page* (not *category*) and have a trailing slash, like that

```
http://site.com/page/1/
```

(`^` mark the start of the string, `$` mark the end)

**Edit**

For your wordpress issue :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/page/(.*) /category/?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule [...wordpress rules...]
```

Comment: Not Work , I have WordPress in root directory, maybe that cause the problem?

Comment: Yes this is an issue. You can try to put your specific rule at the top of your `.htaccess`, add it an `[L] flag` (at the end of the line) and let the wordpress rules below. You will give your rule an higher priority and the [L] flag tell apache that this is the last rule (it will not interpret the next rules).

Comment: @NuLLeR Note that worpress has yet a powerful tool for rewriting url : if the page that you want to redirect is a wordpress page, just turn on the [pretty permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: No its not WordPress page, Its WordPress plugin that create dynamic pagination, I test your new code but still not work.

Comment: If this is a plugin you can user wordpress hooks on WP_Rewrite to define new rules : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite